# Проблема с populate и вложенностью [mongoose]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Не могу сделать populate c применением вложенности. 
Вот пример моих моделей:

```
// Схема открытых кейсов
const openedSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user',
    required: [true, 'user is required'],
    index: true
  },
  weapon: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'cases.weapons',
    required: [true, 'weapon is required'],
    index: true
  },
  sellPrice: {
    type: Number,
    default: null
  },
  status: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
});

const opened = mongoose.model('opened', openedSchema);

// список сейсов
const casesSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: [true, 'name is required']
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, 'price is required']
  },
  weapons: [ {
    weapon: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'weapon',
      index: true
    }
  } ]
}, {
  timestamps: false
});

const cases = mongoose.model('cases', casesSchema);

// схема для оружия

const weaponSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: [true, 'name is required']
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, 'price is required']
  },
  autoship: {
    count: Number,
    status: Boolean,
    price: Number
  }
}, {
  timestamps: false
});

const weapon = mongoose.model('weapon', weaponSchema);
```

Как выглядят сами документы

```
// cases
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "59653bcfa9ac622e1913e10c"
    },
    "name": "test case #1",
    "price": 256,
    "weapons": [
        {
            "weapon": {
                "$oid": "59653bcfa9ac622e1913e10b"
            },
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "59653bcfa9ac622e1913e10d"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "59653d3279aeda2fda9fb490"
            },
            "weapon": {
                "$oid": "59653c5d069f562eb0ba4ef3"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "59653d38ba04de2fdddc459f"
            },
            "weapon": {
                "$oid": "59653c893a772e2ef7b65a29"
            }
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
// opened
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5965d134c8c95972a1a498f5"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2017-07-12T07:35:16.419Z"
    },
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2017-07-12T07:35:16.419Z"
    },
    "user": {
        "$oid": "5965d0d6ea9db872360db98b"
    },
    "weapon": {
        "$oid": "59653bcfa9ac622e1913e10d"
    },
    "status": 0,
    "sellPrice": null,
    "__v": 0
}
// weapon
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "59653bcfa9ac622e1913e10b"
    },
    "name": "AWP | Fever Dream",
    "price": 300,
    "autoship": {
        "status": true,
        "price": 167,
        "count": 5
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

Модель `cases` имеет в себе массив под моделей `_id` которых указывает на её саму, а `weapon._id` для осуществления `populate` к модели `weapon`, в модели `opened` строка `weapon` служит для `populate` к массиву под моделей `cases.weapons`. Так вот, делаю я так:

```
 opened.find()
 .populate('cases.weapons')
    .then(_opened => {
      console.log(_opened);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      logger.error(err);
    });
```

но `populate` не срабатывает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения проблемы требуется в коллекцию `opened` добавить следующее:

```
case: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'cases',
    required: [true, 'case is required'],
    index: true
  },
```

Чтобы в нужный момент знать какой кейс был открыт.
И так же переделать ключ `weapon`в коллекции `opened` и обращаться не к `cases.weapons`, а напрямую к `weapon`:

```
  weapon: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'weapon',
    required: [true, 'weapon is required'],
    index: true
  },
```

Т.к. админ когда-то захочет извлечь какой-то предмет из кейса и все объединения который проходили через эту связь полетят к чертям.
Это не претендует на отличное решение(объединения для mongodb это не хорошо), но всё же имеет право на жизнь.